# What does the 'env' property in 'app.php' do?

Tags: php, configuration, upgrade, laravel-5

The [Laravel upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0) recommends, when upgrading to 5.2, to add the `env` property to the `app.php` configuration file like this:

```
'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),
```

What does this do? And how to go about this in the local testing environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel is set up to read a .env file for various settings, and one of them is the "environment".

The line you mention is setting 'env' to whatever is in the .env file in the variable 'APP_ENV', or setting it to the default 'production'.

This way, you can just edit the .env file and set the 'APP_ENV' variable to 'testing', 'local', or 'production' and affect changes across the whole application.  This is useful because it means you could install your application on different servers and have it feature different configurations based on whether you have set the environment to 'testing', 'local', 'production'.

You might want to read the "Configuration" section here and what it says about setting up the environment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/configuration